# Custom Confidence bands with ggplot2 in R?

Tags: r, ggplot2, graph, confidence-interval, table-statistics

I would like to define my own confidence intervals, instead of `ggplot2` automatically calculating them for me. I have put some reproducible code that outputs the graph below. **In the example I have given, how may I define my own lower and upper confidence intervals?**

```
library(ggplot2)
x = 1:10
y = rnorm(10)
upper_confidence_band = y + 1
lower_confidence_band = y - 1
qplot(x,y, geom="smooth")
# `geom_smooth()` using method = 'loess' and formula 'y ~ x'
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks in advance for the help!

Comment: You need to use `geom_ribbon` to add the confidence intervals. How you calculate them is up to you :-) You might find some ideas on this blog post I wrote: http://jamescurran.co.nz/2018/06/adding-multiple-regression-lines-to-a-faceted-ggplot2-plot/